# Munkres Section 20 Exercise 3b. Proof verification.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space with metric $d$.

(a) Show that $d:X\times X\to\Bbb R$ is continuous.
I've shown this already.

(b) Let $X'$ denote a space having the same underlying set as $X$.  Show that if $d:X'\times X'\to\Bbb R:(x,y)\mapsto d(x,y)$ is continuous, then the topology of $X'$ is finer than the topology of $X$.

For $x_0\in X$, $B(x_0,\epsilon)$ can be identified with $(\{x_0\}\times X)\cap d^{-1}([0,\epsilon))$.  Note that $[0,\epsilon)$ is relatively open in the subspace $\Bbb R_{\ge0}$.

By hypothesis $(\{x_0\}\times X')\cap d^{-1}([0,\epsilon))$ is relatively open, hence $B(x_0,\epsilon)=\pi_2((\{x_0\}\times X')\cap d^{-1}([0,\epsilon)))$ is an open set of $X'$.

I'm fairly sure this argument works, but not entirely confident.  Is this right?  Is there an easier way?

Comment: When you say $X\times X\to \Bbb R$, I assume you mean the metric $d$. It helps to be clear about that. Same for $X'\times X'\to \Bbb R$. _Tell us_ that $d$ is the function you're referring to, so we don't have to guess.

Comment: Yes,  I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the family of maps indexed by $x\in X$

$$ X \stackrel {d(x,-)} \longrightarrow\mathbb R.$$

The preimages of open sets here forms a basis for the topology $\tau$ of the metric space $X$. If this map is continous wrt to another topology $\tau'$, that means that all open sets of $\tau$ are contained already in $\tau'$.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I this is much cleaner.  I knew I was missing something simple.